# How to split Visual Studio project into 2 separate applications (that won't be merged back again) in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn

I have application written in C# WinForms developed in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I am only developer of this application and I use Tortoise SVN for it. Application is hitting 200k lines and I want to split it into 2 different programs (even change naming of application) as actually application supports 2 different companies/departments so it would be better for me to have them as separate projects. At time of projecting the app it was easier to start since I have used code from old application and added more code to support other company/department hence it was build as one project. But now since the application is mature enough I would like to split it into two or even 3 projects as it no longer makes sense.

How can I do that? Will branching help with this? I read that it's to test out features and merge back again but it's not something I want. At best I would like to have 2-3 separate directories so I was even thinking of simply copying application sources multiple times and delete `Tortoise SVN` files from the copied applications so I could change their names and Commit them again into Tortoise SVN as new applications and then slowly cut out unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can branch and then delete in one branch half the project and delete in the other branch the other half of the project, or you can duplicate the repository and do the same (but then you'll lose the "option" of merging back some files), or you can simply have 1 repository for two solutions. You create an empty solution and begin adding projects/files.

In the end there isn't a single "perfect" solution. But none of these three solutions are inherently "worse" than the others.

I'll add that if you split the repositories and then want to "clean" their history a little, it could be complex. As written here: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal it's complex to remove a file + file history (`obliterate` as they call it) from a repository.

Comment: It seems like an easier thing to do would be copy the directory of project 2 times and clean them up from Tortoise SVN files and then commit them again as new projects. That way all history etc is gone and it's like 2 new projects.

Comment: @MadBoy But then as you said you lose all the history. I always considered the history to be the most important part of a VCS. Without history what is a VCS? A tool to branch and merge?

Comment: Well considering it will be lost for only 2 new projects and the first one stays with all history this should be no problem for me.

Comment: @MadBoy It can be quite complex to search for the history of a file you deleted! (you can't simply right-click view log history because you don't have anymore the file to right click) This unless you create a Branch/Tag only for browsing the old history (then you can keep it around just for this reason).

Comment: TO be honest I never ever used any history :-) I do it just so I am safe if something really bad happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make two new branches.  Then you have the history, and you can compare your current working version against the original.

Comment: Will it be easy for me to distinguish which one i am working on? Like change project name, maybe have 2 different directories?